# How to assign a local block in tensor without eval in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Assume I have a tensor **t1** with shape [1,32,16,1], and another tensor **t2** with shape [1,10,12,1] in tensorflow graph

How can I assign t2 into local block in t1(**t1[1, 11:20, 4:15, 1]=t2** in numpy way)

or do adding(**t1[1, 11:20, 4:15, 1]+t2** in numpy way)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it out yourself? That kind of slicing is in fact supported in numpy:

```
    t1[:,11:20,4:15,:]=t2
    t1[:,11:20,4:15,:]+t2
```

Both work.

Comment: I' m sorry I didn't describe the problem clearly. My true question is how to use above np way in tensorflow. I''ll edit it.

Comment: Processes all the arrays using numpy and numpy slicing, and then feed the processed arrays into their respective placeholders using feed_dict?